# Asynchronous UI Pattern on UWA

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await, win-universal-app

I am following [this great article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx) from Stephen about asynchronous UI, but unfortunately this does not apply to Universal Windows Apps, since CommandManager class is not available.

How can I workaround this limitation?

This is the base type for Async Commands:

```
public abstract class AsyncCommandBase : IAsyncCommand
{
  public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);
  public abstract Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
  public async void Execute(object parameter)
  {
    await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
  }
  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
 {
add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
 }
  protected void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
 {
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
}
```

Comment: This "pattern" of using `CommandManager` is awful anyways and has serious performance impact when you have many commands in a complex application, because it will force **ALL** commands to reevaluate their `CanExecute` method

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, this "pattern" shouldn't be used because of it's impact on performance when you have many commands registered.

Any call to `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` will force WPF to validate every single registered command and it's `CanExecute(...)` methods.

Instead, just declare the event and only let WPF register to it

```
public abstract class AsyncCommandBase : IAsyncCommand
{
    ...
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        // C# 6.0, otherwise assign the handler to variable and do null check
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    ...
}
```

Whenever you want to invalidate the command you still just use `command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();`. If you want to trigger revalidation of multiple commands, you need to manage it yourself (i.e. creating a `CompoundCommand` or something similar where you register your commands to groups).